# Diffusion PDE Initial condition

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

I am looking at the PDE book by Strauss page 49:. A "test" solution of the diffusion equation is given by:

$u(x,t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} Q(x-y,t) \phi'(y)dy$

To show that this is a solution, we have to show that $u(x,0) = \phi(x)$.

So, clearly:

$u(x,0) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} Q(x-y,0) \phi'(y)dy$

The next line, he writes that this is equal to $\int_{-\infty}^x \phi'(y) dy$. This is where I am having some trouble.

We started with special initial conditions that: $Q(x,0) = 1$ for $x > 0$ and $Q(x,0) = 0$ for $x < 0$.

Since the integral is written in terms of $y$, I don't know how they got the limits of $-\infty$ to $x$.

Comment: Consider $Q(x-y,0)$ as we integrate over $-\infty < y < \infty$. In order to have $Q$ being non-zero we need $x-y>0$ which means $y < x$ so the integrand is non-zero only for $-\infty < y < x$.

Comment: Oh. I see it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $Q(x-y,0)=1$ for $x-y>0$ and $Q(x-y,0)=0$ for $x-y<0$. Thus $Q(x-y,0)\phi^\prime(y)$ is non-zero if and only if $x>y$ and in particular, for $x>y$, $Q(x-y,0)\phi^\prime(y)=\phi^\prime(y)$. Outside of this region $Q(x-y,0)\phi^\prime(y)=0$. For this reason
$$u(x,0)=\int_\mathbb{R}Q(x-y,0)\phi^\prime(y)\, dy = \int_{\{x>y\}}Q(x-y,0)\phi^\prime(y)\, dy +\int_{\{x\leq y\}}Q(x-y,0)\phi^\prime(y)\, dy$$
From this
$$u(x,0)=\int_{\{x>y\}}Q(x-y,0)\phi^\prime(y)\, dy + 0 = \int_{-\infty}^x Q(x-y,0)\phi^\prime(y)\, dy$$